# div overflow problem

Tags: html, css, layout

I have an outer div

```
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
min-heigth: 450px;
```

containing a div

```
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 10px;
```

The inner div is bigger than the min-heigth of the outer div and I see that the outer div is not scaling to the content of the inner div. Capping off the bottom content of the inner div.

How can I define the outer (or inner) div to scale vertically to the content (of the inner div)

Thanks

Comment: Don't absolutely position the inner `div`. Could you make a [jsFiddle test case](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your HTML/CSS?

Comment: Possibly irrelevant to your question, but thought I'd mention that if this is a direct cut-n-paste from your CSS, then you have a typo: `min-heigth: 450px;` should be `min-height: 450px;`. That could cause other issues. If it's not a direct cut-n-paste then disregard :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@trascher; It's possible but you have add extra markup because when you give a child div an `absolute position` then it's parent div is not consider it's height.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/6UksD/1/

**CSS:**

```
#outer
{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 450px;
    background:red;
    margin:10px 0 0 10px;
    width:200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#inner
{
    position:relative;
    background:black;
    height:600px;
    width:100px;
    margin:10px 0 0 10px;
    float:left;
}
#abinner
{
    position:absolute;
    background:yellow;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="abinner"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove the `min-height`on your outer div, and then instead of absolutely positioning the inner one, put a 10px padding on the outer one.

```
#outerDiv {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:10px;
}

#innerDiv {
  /*Stuff*/
}
```

Do provide us with an example though, it's hard to see the context...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the stuff

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>

#outer
{
    width:300px;
     height:auto;

}
#inner
{
    width:200px;
    height:300px;

}
```

I think this is thing you want:http://jsfiddle.net/anish/ZjQTt/

set inner content height according to your wish.the outer div expanded automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning doesn't increase the height of it's parent element.

1. You either set the height of the outer div manually
2. You make the inner div to have margin top/left of 10px
3. You increase the height of the outer div using javascript.